# Що означає слово "друбок"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У вірші Ліни Костенко ["Підмосковський етюд"](http://vitchyzna.ukrlife.org/3_4_05Kostenko.htm) натрапила на такі рядки із незрозумілим для мене словом:

> То там, то там над соснами димочок,
>
> і в крижаних бурульках бахроми
>
> стоїть такий чудесний теремочок -
>
> **друбок** бурштину в кружеві зими!

Заглянула у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/drubok), однак такого там не знайшла. То що ж означає це слово?

Comment: Про всьак підказка: [јак вже знајемо](/a/4427/585), ненаголошене **о** при **а** може ставати јак *а*. Але переважно воно стаје **у**, в декотрих випадках дльа літературнојі це стаје усталеним, јак от слово _па́р**у**бок_, Дльа порівньаньа діјалект, [де таке стало поширеніше](//zbruc.eu/node/81669): _Ни плач, панцюнийко, я го навчу г**у**в**у**ри́ти_. Тут випадок складненькиј дешчо, бо треба знати шче про [ікавину](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ікавізм), бо тут **і** на місці **о**, хоча можна здогадати сьа через дьіјеслово _др**о**бити_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [Словнику української мови за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA) знаходимо:

> **Друбо́к,** бка́, м. = **Дрібок.** Мені небагацько треба: соли друбок, хліба шматок та горілки чарка. Ном. № 12175. Ум. Друбочок. Нема соли друбочка. Чуб. V. 496.

Далі за посиланням :

> **ДРІБО́К,** бка́, ч. Те саме, що **дрі́бка**

Далі:

> **ДРІ́БКА,** и, ж.
>   1. Невелика частина, мала кількість чого-небудь, Їм страшно навіть подумати про такі гроші, хоч самі по дрібці ще більше тратять (Фр., VII, 1951, 360).
>
> 2. Те саме, що гру́дочка. Виступили повагом три діди, Три чисті білі хліби несучи з дрібками солі, звичаєм прадавнім, І подали з уклоном трьом грузинам (Рильський, І, 1956, 422); Коли хурщики виймали їсти свіжу булку з ковбасою — Майдан мав для того чорний хліб і дрібку цукру (Кач., II, 1958, 8).